How to search or sort contacts cards for large photos or other large data?
iCloud quit syncing Contacts. Apple says I seem to have hit one or more of their limits: https://support.apple.com/en-us/103188

Maximum size of a contact card: 256KB
Maximum size of a contact photo: 224KB
Maximum size of all contact cards:

Card text: 48MB
Card photos: 200MB

Supported file types for a contact photo: JPEG, BMP, PNG, GIF

Apple also says they know of no way to determine which limit I might have exceeded, nor where the limit might be broken.
I have searched the App Store and the internet for how I might solve this, to no avail.
Would you know of any method to (or an app that can) sort (or search) my Contacts cards by card size (or photo size, or any field size, or photo file type)?
